# What is the correct format for hibernate parameter names

Tags: hibernate, filter, parameters, format

I am using Hibernate Entity manager 5.1.8 Final

I have the following filter definitions annotating a class called Submission.

```
@FilterDefs({
    @FilterDef(name=Submission.BY_DATE_RANGE_FILTER, 
            parameters={ @ParamDef( name=Submission.WITH_START_PARAM, type="java.util.Date" ),
                         @ParamDef( name=Submission.WITH_END_PARAM,   type="java.util.Date" )
    }),
    @FilterDef(name=Submission.BY_INSTID_SET_FILTER, 
               parameters=@ParamDef( name=Submission.BY_INSTID_SET_PARAM, type="java.lang.String" ) ),
    })

@Filters({
    @Filter(name=Submission.BY_DATE_RANGE_FILTER, condition="added <= :lastDay and added > :firstDay"),
    @Filter(name=Submission.BY_INSTID_SET_FILTER, condition="instid in :byinstidsetparam"),
})
```

and the following static final definitions within the class

```
public static final String WITH_START_PARAM = "firstDay";
public static final String WITH_END_PARAM = "lastDay";
public static final String BY_INSTID_SET_PARAM = "byinstidsetparam";
```

When I attempt to activate either, or both, of these filters, Hibernate throws an Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid filter-parameter name format
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.LoadQueryInfluencers.parseFilterParameterName(LoadQueryInfluencers.java:144)
   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.processDynamicFilterParameters(JoinProcessor.java:232)
   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SyntheticAndFactory.addWhereFragment(SyntheticAndFactory.java:98)
... more ...
```

Googling for the source gave me this:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.CR3/org/hibernate/engine/spi/LoadQueryInfluencers.java#LoadQueryInfluencers.parseFilterParameterName%28java.lang.String%29

which, sure enough, throws this exception if the parameter name does not contain a '.'.

Here's the mystery though.

- If I rename my parameters to contain a '.' I get the very same exception thrown at the very same place.
- No example that I can find on the net of the filter param feature (including the official Hibernate docs) has a '.' in the parameter name.

Its possible that this source code is a red herring.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?  Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you determine ' **:** '  in query without any parameter.

Comment: If `':'` is intentional, you can replace it with `CHR(58)`.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't looking in the relevant place.  Here's the definition of the filter name (not parameter) constants referenced above

```
public static final String BY_STUDENTID_FILTER = "with-studentid";
public static final String BY_DATE_RANGE_FILTER = "within-daterange";
public static final String BY_INSTID_SET_FILTER = "with-instructorset";
```

Removing the '-' from these names solved the problem.

Summary, Filter names cannot contain hyphens.  If they do, Hibernate will complain that the filter *parameter* definition has the wrong format.